# Value / pair update in awk

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a basic `CSV` that contains key/value. The first two columns being the key and the third column being the value.

**Example file1:**

```
12389472,1,136-7402
23247984,1,136-7402
23247984,2,136-7402
34578897,1,136-7402
```

And in another file I have a list of keys that need their value changed in the first file. I'm trying to change the value to `136-7425`

**Example file2:**

```
23247984,1
23247984,2
```

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{FS=",";OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]="136-7425";next}{$3=a[$1,$2]}1' file2 file1 > output
```

Which is working but it's leaving the value blank for keys not found in `file2`. I'd like to only change the value for keys present in `file2`, and leave the current value for keys not found.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps there's an easier way to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're just zapping the third field for keys that don't exist in the first file. Try this:

```
awk '{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]="136-7425";next} ($1,$2) in a{$3=a[$1,$2]} 1' file2 file1 > output
```

or (see comments below):

```
awk '{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{seen[$1,$2]++;next} seen[$1,$2]{$3="136-7425"} 1' file2 file1 > output
```

FYI an array named `seen[]` is also similarly and commonly used to remove duplicates from input, e.g.:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: This seems to be working, thank you. So ($1,$2) in a{$3=a[$1,$2]} checks to ensure that the key is in the array, correct?

Comment: Correct. Another common way to solve the problem is the solution @Kent posted, which usually use an array named `seen[]` to indicate the index has been seen before. I'll update my answer to include that version too.

Answer (score 4):

this line should work for you:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=1;next}a[$1,$2]{$3="136-7425"}7' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What does the 7 at the end indicate?

Comment: same as your `1`, it (non-zero number) does print. @TyC